# Setting a ModelAttribute's date field when receiving a String from an <input type="date"> in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC and having an issue with submitting a form when the ModelAttribute for that form contains a `Date` field. When I make a POST my Apache Tomcat log gives me the following warning but no stack trace:

```
WARN    2017-10-12 11:51:05,574 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

My `@PostMapping` controller method never even gets called. The thing is, when I change the field from `Date` to `String`, the POST request goes through without any further changes.

My form class:

```
public class MyForm {
    private Date myDate;
    // Other unrelated fields

    // getters + setters
}
```

My JSP:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/new/MyForm" modelAttribute="myForm">
    // Unrelated inputs

    <form:label path="myDate">Follow-up date</form:label>
    <form:input path="myDate" type="date"/>

    <input type="submit" name="complete" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

My Controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void dataBinding(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    CustomDateEditor dateEditor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, dateEditor);
}

@PostMapping(value="new/MyForm", params="complete")
public ModelAndView submitMyForm(@ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm form,
        BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("myURL");
    }

    return this.saveAndRedirect(form);
}
```

If I take out the date input from the JSP completely, everything goes through and gets submitted as expected. If I change the `Date` type to `String` in the Form class, again, the form gets submitted (but I would need to convert the String to a Date manually each time in each controller that uses Date for database storage, and vice versa to display the retrieved Date).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show how you write the jsp action form?

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
<form:label path="myDate">Follow-up date</form:label>
<form:input path="myDate" type="date"/>
```

to

```
<form:label>Follow-up date</form:label>
<form:input path="myDate" type="date"/>
```

we should not bind the date with label

and please let me know if that works

Comment: labels are forced to have a path element. If I remove it I get the following error: `According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute [path] is mandatory for tag [label]`. I removed the label line completely, but am continuing to have the same issue. I appreciate your responses though, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: if you could provide me the code I will happy to find out the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyForm{
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)
    private Date date;

}
```

Declaring @DateTimeFormat at field specify the field must be format to date or time.So basically everytime u try to get a date value it will automatically format to
date or time. And regarding your controller after form submit the request is not mapped to the controller, I guess probably it is your request handler path.

Try change to: @PostMapping(value="/new/MyForm", params="complete")

Comment: This could be improved by explaining how/why it solves the problem. You also didn't answer the asker's question of what they are doing wrong.